# Which Books in English Go into Kabbalistic Depth of the Beit Hamikdash?

Tags: product-recommendation, beis-hamikdash, mysticism-kabbalah, symbols-symbology

Looking for a reference book in English from the mekorot on every aspect of the Beit Hamikdash.

Comment: I added some tags based on inference. Is there a particular area you're researching or a question about the _mikdash_ you seek to answer? Editing them into the question would make it more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Everything inside the Beit Hamikdash and its symbolism

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent book in English with beautiful illustrations by Rabbi Chaim Clorfene who draws heavily from Sefer Mishkanei Elyon by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato. It sounds like it may be exactly what you are looking for. Here is a link to his [website](https://www.chaimclorfene.com/the-messianic-temple). The book can be ordered on Amazon.

Comment: I don't know if this is the book. I am looking for the correlations in the Beit Hamikdash to the human being.

Comment: @JSarai This is also discussed in this book.

Comment: @JSarai edit that into the question and you will likely recieve an answer more closely matched to what you're looking for

Comment: @JoshK The moderators can confirm this, but I believe once a question has received an answer which gets up votes, the question is not supposed to be changed/edited from that point further because it could invalidate the answer provided.